# Disadvantages to flattening object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have some data that lends itself well to a nested categorical structure. At first I was using nested maps to represent it, but I'm thinking maybe it would be more space-efficient to just use a flat structure that's indexed into by tuples containing each category keyword.

For example, let's say I have the data dog,cat,tree,gold,silver
At first, let's say, I had the following structure, where an arrow denotes a key-value pair in a map

```
animal -> {barks -> "dog"
           purrs -> "cat"}
plant  -> {rooted -> "tree"}
mineral -> {golden -> "gold"
            silvery -> "silver"}
```

But now, I'm thinking why not just have

```
['animal','barks'] -> 'dog'
['animal', 'purrs'] -> 'cat'
['plant', 'rooted'] -> 'tree'
['mineral','golden'] -> 'gold
['mineral', 'silvery'] -> 'silver'
```

all in the same one flat object?

Are there any performance, style, or otherwise disadvantages to this?

One I can think of is that it's harder to, in this example, get all minerals, or all animals - I have to do a linear search through all the keys to collect that. Is there anything else?

Comment: The main goal of any data structure design is to serve the needs of the queries needed of it.  We can't really help you decide which is best without knowing what types of queries you need to make, how often you make each one, how large the data set is likely to be and how important performance is for which types of queries.  If the data set is small and performance is not crucial for any particular query, then pick the simplest way to implement that will likely take the least time to code and have the fewest complications.  Decisions beyond that are to optimize for a particular need.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your response. I should have been clearer - taking that as a given, I was wondering if there are any blanket disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first off, until ES6 becomes widely supported, you won't able to use arrays as object keys, so you would have to then include some other level of indirection to store things properly, perhaps something like:

```
{
    'animal~barks': 'dog',
    'animal~purrs': 'cat',
    ...
}
```

That really makes coding with this harder.

You also would increase your memory consumption, presumably with large collections by repeating, e.g., 'animal'.

So I think there are several strikes against this.

Comment: Well that certainly moots the question. Thanks!